# Is QTIMZON used to convert dates/timestamps on DB2 for i?

Tags: ibm-midrange, db2-400

Concerning [DB2 for i](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/power/software/i/db2/), are timestamp columns converted to UTC 0000 from the timezone specified in system setting QTIMZON?  For example, if QTIMZON is set to UTC -0400 does any conversion to UTC 0000 take place before inserting a row?

I ask because [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html) and [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-datetime.html) both convert to/from UTC to the operating-system-specified timezone.

I am aware of the [CURRENT TIMEZONE](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/db2/rbafzc2curtz.htm) special register which leads me to believe no conversion is done automatically, but I wanted to be sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DB/2 for i does not appear to perform any timezone conversion according to the following test:

```
CHGSYSVAL SYSVAL(QTIMZON) VALUE(QN0500EST3)
```

```
CREATE TABLE QTEMP/TEST AS (SELECT NOW() TS FROM SYSIBM/SYSDUMMY1) WITH DATA

SELECT TS FROM QTEMP/TEST
....+....1....+....2....+.
TS                        
2014-04-21-17.52.17.813498
```

```
CHGSYSVAL SYSVAL(QTIMZON) VALUE(Q0000UTC)
```

```
SELECT TS FROM QTEMP/TEST
....+....1....+....2....+.
TS                        
2014-04-21-17.52.17.813498
```

Comment: James what version on you on?  IIRC there's improved timezone support in later versions...

Comment: @Charles That test was performed on V7R1.

Comment: note that there is a CURRENT_TIMEZONE special register that allows you to convert to UTC.

Comment: @JamesA, yes it *appears* that is the case.  I've done similar tests but was hoping for a definitive answer.  I've asked IBM to comment on this thread so we don't have to guess.